# costom http Header can not get respect value

Tags: node.js, http-headers

I am trying to write a server app that client sends an HTTP request with two custom headers `targeturl` and `setheader`.And the server gets the value from that.

And then server create a new request whit URL and headers get from this client.

```
var http = require('http')
var request = require('request')
const express = require('express')

var app = express();

app.get("/",(req,res)=>{

    let targeturl = req.headers.targeturl
    let headers1 = req.headers.setheaders
    let headers2 = { 'x-shard': 'shopid=1354933;loc=138.252924,36.20482399999999' }

    console.log(headers)
    console.log(headers2)


    getData(targeturl,headers1)//wrong response 
    getData(targeturl,headers2)//right response

    res.send("ok")
})


function getData(url,header){

    var options = {
        url:url,
        headers:header
    }
    var data=''
    function callback(error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            data = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(data)
        }

    }
    request(options, callback);
}
```

When I create a request from the client, this strange thing happened.

this is output:

```
{ 'x-shard': 'shopid=1354933;loc=138.252924,36.20482399999999' }
{ 'x-shard': 'shopid=1354933;loc=138.252924,36.20482399999999' }
//a right response
//anther wrong response
```

In my bash,`headers1` and `header2` are exactly with same chars.That confused me a lot, I really can not find what is the difference between them.Is there some different than cannot show on bash?

Comment: Just debug it all the way down. Are you sure that differences in response caused by arguments? If arguments are identical looks like request handler is stateful and one of the requests fails because of that state while another one succeeds. Just check it out deeper in your code.

Comment: @tuxSlayer I had debug in many ways and separate one by one.This is the only problem that I had found.